# Read Large Gzip Files in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to read a gzip file (with size around 150 MB) and using this script (which I know is badly written):

```
import gzip

f_name = 'file.gz'

a = []

with gzip.open(f_name, 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        a.append(line.split(' '))

new_array1 = []

for l in a:
    for i in l:
        if i.startswith('/bin/movie/tribune'):
            new_array1.append(l)

filtered = []

for q in range(0, len(new_array1)):
    filtered.append(new_array1[q])

#at this point filtered array can be printed
```

The problem is that I am able to read files upto 50 MB using this technique into an array, but file sizes from 80 MB and above are not readable. Is there some problem with a technique that I am using or is there a memory constraint? If this is the second case, then what should be the best technique to read a large gz file (above 100 MB) in python array? Any help will be appreciated.

Note: I am not using NumPy because I ran into some serious issues with C compilers on my server which are required for numpy and therefore I am not able to have it. So, please suggest something that uses native Pythonic approach (or anything other than NumPy). Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "not readable"?

Comment: Do you get some error message?

Comment: I am getting memory error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that the problem is constructing `a` in your code, as that will undoubtedly contain a massive number of entries if your .gz is that large. This modification should solve that problem:

```
import gzip

f_name = 'file.gz'

filtered = []
with gzip.open(f_name, 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        for i in line.split(' '):
            if i.startswith('/bin/movie/tribune'):
                filtered.append(line)
                break # to avoid duplicates
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot dude. I will try these methods and let you guys know.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is the memory consumption (you didn't include the error message...), you can save up a lot of memory by avoiding storing the temporary lists, by using [generators](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

E.g.

```
import gzip
f_name = 'file.gz'

def get_lines(infile):
    for line in infile:
        yield line.split()

def filter1(line_tokens):
    return any( token.startswith('/bin/movie/tribune')  for token in line_tokens )

def filter2(line_tokens):
    # was there a filter2?
    return True

infile = gzip.open(f_name, 'r')

filtered = ( line_tokens for line_tokens in get_lines(infile) if filter1(line_tokens) and filter2(line_tokens) )

for line in filtered:
    print line
```

In my example `filter2` is trivial, because it seems your `filtered` list is just a (un-filtered) copy of `new_array1`...

This way, you avoid storing the entire content in memory.  Note that since `filtered` is a generator, you can only iterate over it once. If you do need to store it entirely, do `filtered = list(filtered)`

Comment: I am not sure about `filter1()`... `line` is only one line, isn't it?

Comment: @glglgl, no, `get_lines` splits it up. I'll rename the variable to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks, a lot. I will try these methods and update you guys shortly.

Comment: this one is also good..works totally fine. Thanks a lot, I appreciate it. :-)